# Default autowire with @Component

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I have an interface its 2 implementation. I annotate both implementations by @Component. How can I specific one of them to be the default bean when will be used to inject by @Autowired as default.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`@Primary`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation on the bean which you think given higher priority.

from doc

> Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple
>   candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency. If
>   exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the
>   autowired value.
>
> May be used on any class directly or indirectly annotated with
>   Component or on methods annotated with Bean.
>
> Using Primary at the class level has no effect unless
>   component-scanning is being used. If a Primary-annotated class is
>   declared via XML, Primary annotation metadata is ignored, and `<bean
>   primary="true|false"/>` is respected instead.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that our project are using spring 2.5. So it seems that I have to use Qualifier :'(

Answer (score 0):

Autowired works "by type", meaning it can autowire when exactly one bean matches. When more than one bean matches, use Autowired + Qualifier annotations. Qualifier calls out the name of the bean to autowire.

This means when you declare the Components you need to name them as well.